# React error when loading firebase document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a very simple React component, in the componentDidMount() method I fire a call to Firebases firestore to get a document. The first render call displays a template with the caption 'No Items' when the Firebase call has completed it re renders the component successfully with the items data.

However in the process it throws an error onto the console

> index.js:2178 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
>
> Please check the code for the HomePage component.

I have tried looking at other articles but as far I can see I am doing it the right way. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { firestore } from '../firebase/firebase'

class HomePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    
        super(props);   

        this.state = {
            items: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        firestore.collection('item').doc('P1zi3sqkgFuJ6Jw243SA').get().then( o => { 
            this.setState({items: o.data()});
        });         
    
    }

    render() {

        const item = this.state.items
            
        const template = item ? <h1>{item.title}</h1> : <h1>No item</h1>
    
        return(

            <div>
                <h1>Home Page</h1>
                { template}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Is there a parent consuming this component and unmounting it before your request is finished?

Comment: It's a component served by the router, nothing gets passed into it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out why this error appears even though react is rendering the returned items from Firebase just fine.

When the page is refreshed on the component it throws the error, if I navigated to another component then to this one it would not appear. I also noticed that when the bundle is recompiled and that home component is refreshed it fires two request to Firebase.

Not sure what the underlying issue is but at least its a step in the right direction